# Configuring LCDS HTTPProxy service behind a firewall

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, lcds

I have an LCDS server sitting behind a corporate proxy/firewall.

I need to use a configured HTTPProxyService on the LCDS server to make requests out to beyond the firewall (can't go directly from the client because of crossdomain.xml issues)

How do I configure LCDS to use the corporate proxy on it's outbound requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs ftw:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/lcds/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=rpc_config_4.html

Use the `<external-proxy />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

LCDS is using Apache HTTP client in order to establish a connection through an external proxy. All the parameters from the  tag are going to be used in order to initialize an org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials instance (or NTCredentials).

I think that first it's easier if you build a standalone java application using HTTP client to use your corporate proxy (easier from a testing point of view), and after you succeed to find all the settings you can add them into proxy-service.xml (I can help you with that).